# Storing application database schema

Tags: android, sqlite, schema

In example apps database is in most cases single table, so db schema is stored in static variable.

Storing large schema in seperate file is more friendly for me.

How can I do that? I thought about using resources (R.strings.db_schema) but probably there is a better way.

Could somebody give me any advice?

Comment: Read in the file into a string, then pass the string to `execSQL()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the schema data in a raw file under res/raw.  Then you can just load and parse that file the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do is to have a class per table, named after the table with "Table" suffix (e.g. `PlayerTable` or `EventTable`).

These classes contain all the static variable for the table name and all the field names, and they also contain two static methods:

```
public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)
public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
```

So that my `SQLiteOpenHelper` can just call all of them, without having hundreds of static variables with all the fields and create queries. E.g:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    PlayerTable.onCreate(database);
    EventTables.onCreate(database);
    ..... any other table you have .....
}
```

This class is then injected into all my data access objects (select / update / insert queries). For them I have dedicated classes that contain all my methods, by functionality (e.g. `EventHandlingDAO` for all the queries that deal with event handling).

And finally, theses DAO are injected into the activities that need them, when needed.

**EDIT:** A few more details about my code:

My main objects are the DAO (data access objects), in which I have methods like:

```
// in EventHandlingDAO:
public void addEvent(Event event) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + EventTable.EVENT_TABLE_NAME + " (...."); // list of fields and values
    } finally {
        database.close();
    }
}

public List<Event> getAllEvents() {
    final List<Event> result = new ArrayList<Event>();
    SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        final Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT " + EventTable.KEY_NAME + ", " + EventTable.KEY_DATE_AS_STRING + " FROM " + EventTable.TABLE_NAME, null); 
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // ... rest of the logic, that iterates over the cursor, creates Event objects from the cursor columns and add them to the result list
        return result;

    } finally {
        database.close();
    }
}
```

So in that DAO, I have my databaseHelper object, which instanciates my class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` with the methods I talked about above.

And of course, I have interfaces to all my DAO, so that I can inject a Stub or mocked implementation in my tests (or experiment with different implementations if I want to try another solution based on `SharedPreference` for example)

And the code for my `PlayerTable` table:

```
public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE); // TABLE_CREATE is my "CREATE TABLE..." query
}

public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // A bit blunt, that destroys the data unfortunately, I'll think about doing something more clever later ;)
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(database);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any public code to share with your database code management?

Comment: not yet, sorry :) But the principles are basically the ones I stated above. More details: I can add more details in the answer, if you're interested in anything specific.

Comment: Could you show me PlayerTable code and maybe a DAO class that uses PlayerTable?

Comment: Thanks a lot, so PlayerTable only creates or destroys table and Player or Event class are POJO classes?

Comment: Yes. My *Table classes only create/destroy, but their main point is to hold the schema for the table. And Player/Event/etc. are indeed POJO, basically DTO (data transfer objects) that are used only to communicate these concepts between the DAO and my client class (the activity, usually, or any AsyncTask that does something long).

Comment: In fact, I use my database as my memory: every time a modification happens, I save it directly to the DAO, and when I need something I get it from the DAO. That way I'm sure that, whatever happens, the user never loses any information, and the data is saved at all time :) No load/save buttons, they are so 20th century ;) Performance wise, it'a lot quicker than I thought, so it's manageable and remains snappy (And I use transactions when I need to save many things at once, within my DAO methods too)

Comment: You're welcome: my main concern is to try to abstract out everything to separate concerns and make testing easier. Unfortunately, the Android SDK doesn't always make that task easy, but that's usually the case with complex UI frameworks :) (It's a lot worse with Swing!)